# Error in Prim's algorithm implementation, Empty Heap

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, tree, heap

I am trying to implement Prim's minimum spanning tree algorithm using Heaps.
However, as I execute my code I get an exception, that the heap is empty.

After some iterations, it says that heap is empty.
This is the main loop of my algorithm:

```
while(traversed.size() < n){
            Edge optimal = heap.minElem();
            heap.delMin();
            traversed.add(optimal.getDest());
            mst.set(optimal.getSource().getVertex(), optimal.getDest().getVertex(), optimal.getDist());
            mst.set(optimal.getDest().getVertex(), optimal.getSource().getVertex(), optimal.getDist());
            //now compute further adjacent
            getAdjacent(optimal.getDest(),myGraph,heap,traversed);

        }
```

And my getAdjacent method is:

```
private void getAdjacent(Vertex v, CGraph graph, Heap<Edge> heap, Set<Vertex> traversed) throws Exception{
int val;
for(int i = 0; i < graph.numV; i++){
    val = graph.get(v.getVertex(), i);
    if((val != 0) && (val != CGraph.Infinity) && !(traversed.contains(new Vertex(i))) ){
        heap.insert(new Edge(graph.get(v.getVertex(),i),v, new Vertex(i)));
        }

    }
}
```

I have seen that it adds al vertices and ends up like the original graph, so it doesnt mantain the tree property.

Why is this? Anyone has a clue?
Help would be very appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: If it *never* adds vertices to the heap, then why doesn't the algorithm fail after the first iteration? It'd help if you could give some examples of graphs on which it fails, and the vertices in heap, traversed and mst at each step.

Comment: I have updated the code, now it returns the original graph. Thanks for the interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's creating loops because you're only checking whether a vertex is in `traversed' when you insert an edge into a heap. In between that insertion and the same edge being retrieved, other edges may have been retrieved from the heap such that the vertex is already linked to the tree.